# How to substitute variable value in "docker run" command

Tags: bash, shell, docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I am using a bash script and trying to assign a fingerprint value as below

```
export FINGERPRINT=D0:19:C5:80:42:66:56:AC:6F  
docker run --rm -i -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name ucp docker/ucp join --replica --fingerprint $FINGERPRINT
```

However, bash is not at all substituting the value of $FINGERPRINT

Comment: Whats the docker version and your host OS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877186/how-to-use-script-resource-to-substitute-variable-value

Comment: What do you get if you do these after the first line: `echo $FINGERPRINT`, and `echo docker run --rm -i -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name ucp docker/ucp join --replica --fingerprint $FINGERPRINT`

Comment: This should work in bash, however are you sure you are using bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
export FINGERPRINT=D0:19:C5:80:42:66:56:AC:6F
echo `docker run --rm -i -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name ucp docker/ucp join --replica --fingerprint $FINGERPRINT`
```