# How to use script resource to substitute variable value

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using chef script resource and trying to assign a fingerprint value as below

```
script 'retrieve_ucp_master_fingerprint' do  
  interpreter "bash"  
  code <<-EOH  
      export FINGERPRINT=D0:19:C5:80:42:66:56:AC:6F  
      docker run --rm -i -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name ucp docker/ucp join --replica --fingerprint $FINGERPRINT
  EOH  
end
```

However, chef is not at all substituting the value of $FINGERPRINT

Comment: How about responding to comments to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876613/how-to-substitute-variable-value-in-docker-run-command) before asking a new, almost identical one?

Answer (score 1):

`$FINGERPRINT` is bash syntax, Chef is not involved. You can use `#{}` to interpolate Ruby expressions in some kinds of Ruby string literals, but you would have to say where that data is coming from.